# Vue CLI3: can't change favicon

Tags: browser-cache, favicon

It seems like I can't change my `favicon`. I already tried the following (based on similair questions here on stack):

- Clear browser history (Chrome & Edge)
- Restart computer
- Restart development serve
- Trying it in Chrome incognito

But still, I see the Vue icon. even after I deleted the `vue` icon from the project. My favicon is a PNG. My `index.html` looks like this:

`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.png">`

This one seems to be a tough one to crack..

Any thoughts?

**SOLUTION**

At production build the icons for favicon are injected from `img/icons`. I Didn't change these. After replacing these icons with those of my own, all was right.

Comment: Browser's are notorious for caching favicons. Try opening your site, right-click and select _"View page source"_ (or your browser's equivalent) then click the favicon link. If you don't see the new image, do a hard refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R / Command+Shift+R)

Comment: Will take a look at this this weekend @phil